# Extending an image with a GUID

Tags: .net, vb.net

I would like to be able to specify a GUID for an image so that I can reliably indentify this image in a List(Of Image).

I would like to be able to write

```
Dim nImage As New Image(...)
nImage.GUID = "my guid"
```

I guess I have to use an Extension.

Can somebody tell me how this would be done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont think an Extension method does what you think it does.  The tag for it tells us:

> > ... Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types without creating a new derived type...

You want to add something like a property, not a method to it.  Since, really what you seem to want is a way to *associate* a `GUID` with an image, a simple class or even a `Dictionary(Of Guid, Image)` may be all you need.  As will be seen, a Guid is about the most unfriendly identifier to work with in code.

#### Dictionary Form

I will use `Guid.ToString()` because you cant really type a `Guid` in code (you can parse one from a string).

```
Private imageCol As Dictionary(Of String, Image)
...

imageCol = New Dictionary(Of String, Image)
' zfiles is just some images to work with
For Each s As String In zFiles
    imageCol.Add(Guid.NewGuid.ToString, Image.FromFile(s))
Next
```

It is just not a friendly identifier:

[image]

#### Class Method

Another way to create the association is a simple class.  This is probably a bit closer to what you actually asked for.

```
Public Class ImageItem
    ' ToDo: make readonly
    Public Property [Image] As Image
    Public Property Id As String

    Public Sub New(i As Image, g As Guid)
        Image = i
        Id = g.ToString
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Id
    End Function

End Class
```

This is really just a more longwinded way to do what the dictionary will do.

```
Private imgs As List(Of ImageItem)
... 
imgs = New List(Of ImageItem)
For Each s As String In zFiles
    imgs.Add(New ImageItem(Image.FromFile(s), Guid.NewGuid))
Next
```

Not any friendlier:

[image]

The problem with this one is that you could end up having to resort to queries to find the desired item, at least with the dictionary you can get it quickly using the key (guid string).

A better identifier might be the file name or image description ("Hand-washing").